# Saving emails via harmon.ie - what if the person viewing them does not have outlook?

Tags: harmon.ie

When dragging emails into harmon.ie from outlook and saving to a SharePoint location what happens if a person viewing the email at a later time does not have outlook and uses something else like lotus notes?

Answer (score 0):

Harmon.ie saves the Outlook email in original format  i.e. .msg format so this email can be opened by any client or browser that can read .msg.
Lotus notes can’t read .msg.

----- Jean